# How to memory map data already in memory to a file

Tags: c, linux, memory-management

I am working on a program which needs to load up to a few hundred images into memory at once.  Each file takes up 100mb so I don't really want to be storing all of them in memory.  I want to memory map the files so the operating system will swap them out when necessary to save physical memory.  Here is what I am wondering.  If I already have the data I want in the file in malloced memory should I open a file descriptor, write the data to the file using write() and then map the file.  Or can I memory map a new file and then copy the data using memcpy.  If I were to create a new file and when I call mmap give it a length large than the file size will it just increase the size of the file on the disk?

Answer (score 0):

From the POSIX standard: “The mmap() function can be used to map a region of memory that is larger than the current size of the object. Memory access within the mapping but beyond the current end of the underlying objects may result in SIGBUS signals being sent to the process.” (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/)

That said, you could try `mmap()` with `MAP_FIXED` over the same memory region you just wrote from, if you got it from a page-aligned `aligned_alloc()` rather than `malloc()`, or free and then `mmap()`.  But note that the OS will page memory you haven’t used for a while to swap anyway, and you can help it out with `posix_madvise()`.

Comment: I know about swap.  But say I was on a system with only 2GB of ram and another 2GB of swap, and I need to process 30GB of images. That is why I want to mmap the files.

Comment: This won't work. From glibc's reference (ch13.8 - Memory-mapped I/O): "Any previous mapping at that address is automatically removed"

Comment: @AlexDarkVoid I think that’s what OP wanted: to remove the previous file mapping and replace it with a new one?

Comment: @Davislor I believe the task is opposite: to create an actual file on disk, which is linked to already existing memory buffer.

Comment: @AlexDarkVoid Ah, in that case, the method should work: There *is* no previous mapping at that address, since it came from either `aligned_alloc` or `posix_memalign` rather than `mmap`. (The alignment, on a page boundary, is necessary for `mmap` with `MAP_FIXED` and an offset of 0, to work.) Then the bytes you just wrote out to disk are mapped back onto the same locations they were written from. Sorry, it’s been a while.